# mysql calculate leaves by duration and date range

Tags: mysql

I have a table.

```
Name    duration    date_leave_from date_leave_to
John    1           2015-03-01      2015-03-02
Doe     .5          2015-03-03      2015-03-04
Doe     1           2015-01-03      2015-01-03
Doe     1           2015-02-04      2015-02-06
```

I would like to get the data (Computation based on date_leave_from and date_leave_to) in the following format:

```
Name      ||  Jan     ||   Feb    ||  March   ||  April 
John      ||  1       ||   0      ||  2       ||  0  
Doe       ||  0       ||   3      ||  1       ||  0
```

And the query is this: which is running.. but not calculated based on a number of leaves.

```
SELECT requester,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`date_leave_from`) = '1' THEN duration else 0 END) AS Jan,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`date_leave_from`) = '2' THEN duration else 0 END) AS Feb,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`date_leave_from`) = '3' THEN duration else 0 END) AS March,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`date_leave_from`) = '4' THEN duration else 0 END) AS April,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`date_leave_from`) = '5' THEN duration else 0 END) AS May,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`date_leave_from`) = '6' THEN duration else 0 END) AS Jun,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`date_leave_from`) = '7' THEN duration else 0 END) AS Jul,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`date_leave_from`) = '8' THEN duration else 0 END) AS Aug,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`date_leave_from`) = '9' THEN duration else 0 END) AS Sep,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`date_leave_from`) = '10' THEN duration else 0 END) AS Oct,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`date_leave_from`) = '11' THEN duration else 0 END) AS Nov,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`date_leave_from`) = '12' THEN duration else 0 END) AS December
FROM tbl_hr_leave_form
GROUP BY requester
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25160/3

Comment: So, the `duration` is not to be taken into account but the difference between from and to? For example, Doe should see 1 for March and not 0.5?

Comment: You asked again the same question.

Comment: yeah duration would be multiply by the date difference